# Access Report Create Mirror Image of Report

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm not sure if Access can do this, but here goes.  I have a report that I am creating that will make up a book.  Each page has the same format.  So, imagine a page in a book.  The outside margin of the page faces away from the binding, the inside margin is closest to the margin :  On the outside of the page, there is a box with some quick fact, on the inside is the body of text.  Because this is a book, every other page would need to be a "mirror" of the previous, in format only.  That is to say, the page should always have the margin, with the box, facing away from the binding.

Is there a setting that would allow for this?  I assume I could just have two reports templates and call it every other time, but if there is a setting, it would be easier.

thanks
jason

Comment: This sounds more like something that would be handled by a (sufficiently sophisticated) driver for a printer that supported duplex printing.

Answer (score 0):

It could be created quite easily controlled by the *page number* in the Format event of the *page header* and page *footer section* and perhaps also the *page details* section.

For odd pages, make visible the page right aligned controls, and make not visible the page left aligned controls - and vice versa for even pages.

```
If Me.Page Mod 2 = 0 Then
    ' Even page.
    ' Show left aligned controls like PageNumberLeft.
    ' Hide right aligned controls like PageNumberRight.
    ' Other settings.
Else
    ' Odd page.
    ' Hide left aligned controls like PageNumberLeft.
    ' Show right aligned controls like PageNumberRight.
    ' Other settings.
End If
```